# Compass/SASS @import path - Absolute

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have the following folder `/app/components/calendar`. My `config.rb` file here is:

```
# Assets directory
sass_dir  = "/assets/sass"
css_dir   = "/assets/css"
# fonts_dir = "/assets/fonts"

# Javascript files
javascripts_dir = "/assets/scripts"

# Image directory
# images_dir = "/assets/images"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :compressed
```

The `app.scss` inside the relative path `/assets/sass` needs to import a file located at `/app/assets/`.

I don't know how to use an absolute path. At the moment, I am including the file using `@import "../../../app/assets/_common.scss"` (the number of `../` is not necessary correct. It is an example).

How can I import my files easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using grunt-contrib-compass, you can add import paths with the `importPath` configuration option.